# Why fixing broken packages / installation in Ubuntu 11.10 takes very long time for Java6?

Tags: installation, java, package-management

Sometime back, I was installing Java JDK and JRE as:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
```

Due to some problems, the installation stopped and it remained broken. As we know, one cannot install **any** package until the broken installations are fully resolved. So, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install       #helps for installing broken packages
```

However, I see that installation of java6 takes **unusually very long time**. Also upon the terminal I see a colorful page while Java6 installation is going on; this page displays various terms and conditions. I can just scroll this page up and down, but can't see what is happening behind. But the main problem is long hours.

Is there any way to fix this problem ? For other installations, I may not need JDK/JRE; so as a last resort, I am ok, if we can remove these broken packages. But how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with that *graphical colorful* page.

After the terms and conditions, in a very small letters `<Ok>` is printed. By pressing `<-` or `->` key, I selected the `<Ok>` "button" and pressed "Enter". This "button" has to be "pressed" only using keyboard. Mouse cannot be used.

This lead me to a new graphical page, where I need to "Accept" terms and conditions (same way using keyboard arrow keys). As soon as, I accepted it, the page disappeared and the installation finished within a minute.